# Hairline crack opening (cold morning) and closing (roof space heats)

Tags: drywall, framing, patching-drywall

I have some hairline cracks on my wall that open and close based on the temp. During cold mornings the cracks open up and close when house heats up.

I don't believe the cracks went through the plasterboard.

[image: Afternoon][image: Morning]

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Having taken the [tour], you should understand that this is a _Question_ and Answer board. Answering questions is what we do, you, however, must actually ask us one. So far, you've just stated a fact. ;)

Comment: [What do these cracks in my drywall indicate?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/166211/what-do-these-cracks-in-my-drywall-indicate)

Comment: [Do drywall cracks pose any risk for further damage?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/196987/do-drywall-cracks-pose-any-risk-for-further-damage)

Comment: [What trade is best to fix the crack in my livingroom ceiling?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/239556/what-trade-is-best-to-fix-the-crack-in-my-livingroom-ceiling)

Comment: [Is this drywall cracking a structural problem?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/217927/is-this-drywall-cracking-a-structural-problem)

Comment: [How can I fix this drywall crack and prevent it from happening again?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/228111/how-can-i-fix-this-drywall-crack-and-prevent-it-from-happening-again)

Comment: [Recurring crack on second floor ceiling](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/65841/recurring-crack-on-second-floor-ceiling)